# how to select active vertex in blender python

Tags: select, blender, vertex

i'm having difficulties with my recent python script. I'm using blender 2.79. As an example let's use a cube that have 2 bones deforming it. Each vertices have vertex weight more than 1 total in value. The script i want to achieve is first, select a vertex, then normalize selected vertex weight, hide the selected vetex, repeat. The code i've written is like this.

```
import bpy
ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
vertcount = len(me.vertices)
sel = ob.name

for i in range(0, vertcount):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
    bpy.data.meshes[sel].vertices[i].select = True #vertex select
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
    bpy.ops.object.vertex_weight_normalize_active_vertex()
    bpy.ops.mesh.hide(unselected=FALSE)
    print("vertex_number",[i],"is_done")
```

Now, i've already know what the problem was. The vertex select syntax was only selecting, but the vertex was not active. And my question is what is the correct syntax for this to be an active selected vertex? I have tried also usong bmesh script. The result is the same, the selected vertex only light up in orange color, while if we manually select it, the color is white.

Comment: You set the active vertex by making it the last one added to the [select history](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16247/935).

Comment: Thank you, for your help. It worked like i hope to be.